# NSSavePanel setNameFieldStringValue:@"Untitled" bug in sandboxed app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sandbox, nssavepanel

Can't find anything in the doc and it seems to be a bug: if specify `@"Untitled"` as `NSSavePanel`'s name filed string value, at runtime textfield is empty. If specify anything else – everything works (OSX 10.8, SDK 10.8). And it happens only in sandboxed app.

```
    NSSavePanel *savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
//  [savePanel setNameFieldStringValue:@"UntitleD"]; // it works
    [savePanel setNameFieldStringValue:@"Untitled"]; // it doesn't

    [savePanel runModal];
```

Here is a sample project to reproduce: https://www.dropbox.com/s/catecqe68a0omp3/savepanel.zip

Does anybody has the same problem?

Comment: How about if you use a file extension?

Comment: If you specify an extension or even change at least one character - it works, but @"Untitled" doesn't.

Comment: I think the filename might have to have a file extension in order to be correct.

Comment: Why? In my case I need to create a directory..

Comment: There are other questions on SO which seem to indicate that; I haven't tested this myself however.

Comment: I reproduced your problem, it certainly appears you have found a bug, and it’s easy to see how naive programming of the PowerBox would have caused this. Please report a RADAR to Apple.